# select a single value from a column after groupby another columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I tried to select a single value of column **class** from each group of my dataframe after i performed the groupby function on the column **first_register** and **second_register** but it seems did not work.

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1],
                   'first_register': ["70/20", "70/20", "70/20", "71/20", "71/20", "71/20", np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN],
                   'second_register': [np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, "72/20", "72/20", "73/20"]})
```

What I have tried and did not work at all:

```
group_by_df = df.groupby(["first_register", "second_register"])
label_class = group_by_df["class"].unique()
print(label_class)
```

How can I select/access each single class label from each group of dataframe?

The desired output can be an ordered list like this to represent each class of each group from the first group to the final group:

```
label_class = [1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
out = df.groupby(["first_register", "second_register"], dropna=False)["class"].first()
print (out)

first_register  second_register
70/20           NaN                1
71/20           NaN                2
NaN             72/20              0
                73/20              1
Name: class, dtype: int64


label_class = out.tolist()
print (label_class)
[1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: dropna=False, I am a bit confused, why is added my solution to your answer?

Comment: I think `group_by_df["class"].first()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `dropna=False`:

```
group_by_df = df.groupby(["first_register", "second_register"], dropna=False)
label_class = group_by_df["class"].unique()


first_register  second_register
70/20           NaN                [1]
71/20           NaN                [2]
NaN             72/20              [0]
                73/20              [1]
Name: class, dtype: object
```

---

if you knok length of unique class is 1 or you want get the first or the last:

```
label_class = group_by_df["class"].first()
```

Or:

```
label_class = group_by_df["class"].last()
```

Comment: How can I get the list after that i.e. label_class = [1, 2, 0, 1]?

Comment: @Erwin: `label_class.str[0]`

Comment: @mozway-- Thanks I used `list(label_class.str[0])`

Comment: I am a bit confused, why is added my solution to your answer?